# How do I create an Extension method that converts a List<T> to another List<T> of a different type at runtime?

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I know this has been asked before, but the solutions I have tried never take into consideration nullable types.

I need something that will be able to handle a conversion like

> List<string> to List<Int32?>, List<string> to List<int>, List<string>
>   to List<double>

etc.

I am trying to create something as follows

```
private void RoutineCompleted(string category, List  Type fieldType = null)
{


//ToNewType is the extension method that I need.
var var convertedList = values.ToNewType(fieldType);

}
```

I have looked at the following code, but it does not do the job:

```
 public static IEnumerable Cast(this IEnumerable self, Type innerType)
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast");
        var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(innerType);
        return genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { self }) as IEnumerable;
    }
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Convert class cannot deal with Nullable types, so I had to special-case those.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var strings = new[] { "1","2","3"};
        var ints = strings.ConvertItems<string, int>().ToList();
        var doubles = strings.ConvertItems<string, double>().ToList();
        var nullableints = strings.ConvertItems<string, int?>().ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TargetType> ConvertItems<SourceType, TargetType>(this IEnumerable<SourceType> sourceCollection)
    {
        var targetType = typeof(TargetType);
        if (targetType.IsGenericType && targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            targetType = targetType.GetGenericArguments().First();
        }
        return sourceCollection.ConvertItems((source) => (TargetType)Convert.ChangeType(source, targetType));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TargetType> ConvertItems<SourceType, TargetType>(this IEnumerable<SourceType> sourceCollection, Converter<SourceType, TargetType> convertor)
    {
        foreach (var item in sourceCollection)
        {
            yield return convertor(item);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: weakly-typed version, when you only know the type at runtime

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var strings = new[] { "1","2","3"};
        var ints = strings.ConvertItems(typeof(int));
        var doubles = strings.ConvertItems(typeof(double));
        var nullableints = strings.ConvertItems(typeof(int?));
        foreach (int? item in nullableints)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable ConvertItems(this IEnumerable sourceCollection,Type targetType)
    {
        if (targetType.IsGenericType && targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            targetType = targetType.GetGenericArguments().First();
        }
        foreach (var item in sourceCollection)
        {
            yield return Convert.ChangeType(item, targetType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas. I think this is close. How do I implement the above to pass in the Type as a parameter? I don't know the Type beforehand. THANKS!!

Comment: Sure, I added it in the edit. Since we do not know the type at compile time, I had to change the signature, so it returs a non-generic IEnumerable

Comment: Hi Tomas. Almost there!!!!! I just tried it. The only issue is that it seems to convert the nullable type into a non-nullable type. Is there any way to keep the type as nullable? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an extension if you can convert using `Convert.To...` methods

```
List<string> strList = ...
List<int> intList = strList.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList();
```

or you can use `Convert.ChangeType`

```
public static IEnumerable<TOut> ConvertTo<TIn, TOut>(this IEnumerable<TIn> list)
{
    return list.Select(o => (TOut)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof (TOut)));
}

List<string> strList = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<int> intList = strList.ConvertTo<string, int>();
```

Comment: How do I implement this so that in takes in the Type as a parameter? For example,   strList.ConvertTo(fieldType)??

Comment: What are you expecting return type should be then? Just IEnumerable?

Answer (score 1):

The conversions you're talking about are not casts per se, but type conversions.

You can do them using Linq, for example like this:

```
var ints = new List(){1,2,3,4,51};
var strings = array.Select(x => x.ToString());
```

or

```
var strings = new List() {"1.56","2.71","3.14"};
var doubles = strings.Select( x => Convert.ToDouble(x));
```

Those give you IEnumerables, but you can make them into Lists using `.ToList()`.

Comment: It seems to me that everyone has their own personal definition of "cast". I would say that it's not a cast unless the *cast operator* is used.

Comment: That's probably a better definition (who am I to challenge THE Eric Lippert?), I thought of a bunch of exceptions to mine the minute I posted it, so I removed it again.

Comment: You can use the `Convert.ChangeType` method mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TTo> ChangeType<TTo, TFrom>(this IEnumerable<TFrom> self)
{
    return self.Select(e => (TTo)Convert.ChangeType(e, typeof(TTo)));
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't wan't to use generic's and you have to pass type: `Type` like this:

```
var list = new List<string> {"1", "3", "4", null};
var result = list.ChangeType(typeof (int?));
```

You can try use this:

```
public static IEnumerable ChangeType(this IEnumerable self, Type type)
{
   var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
   foreach (var obj in self)
   {
       yield return converter.ConvertFrom(obj);
   }
}
```

Comment: Same here. I only know the type to convert to at runtime. How do I pass the type as a parameter?  Thanks :-)

Comment: I don't know the context of your code but is it possible that your `RoutineCompleted` method instead of taking `Type fieldType` can take type argument like this: `RoutineCompleted<T>(string category, List list)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple LINQ `Select`:

```
IEnumerable<string> values = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
var converted = values.Select(PerformConversion);

private int? PerformConversion(string input)
{
   ...
}
```

You will need a different method for each conversion, or a parameterised method to encompassed all of them. For example:

```
private T? PerformConversion<T>(string input) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    return (T?) Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
}
```